# One To Many inverse

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to obtain for ONE user his country. So I have two tables:

**User**

- id
- country_id

**Countries**

- id

I can't decide which relationship to use. I think it is the OneToMany relationship (Inverse) but it implies that the Countries table has the user id.
I can't understand how to use the oneToMany relationship in this case...

Comment: I think `hasOne`

Comment: Same as OneToMany, hasOne implies that the user id is in the Country model, right?

Comment: The `users` table should have a `country_id` on it, so you can specify multiple `users` per `country`. If you did a `user_id` on the `countries` table, you make it so a `country` can only have a single `user`. Makes for a pretty lonely `country` eh?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case at the moment, the table user has a country_id field so that a country can have several users and a user can only have one country.

Comment: Awesome. So what's the issue here? Are you just unsure how to define the relationships? And to clarify, I don't think this is an issue of which to use; the only other real option is allowing a `user` to belong to many `countries`, and a `country` to have many `users`, but that requires a `pivot` and `many-to-many` logic.

Answer (score 0):

Docs link: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

One To Many (Inverse)

Now that we can access all of a post's comments, let's define a relationship to allow a comment to access its parent post. To define the inverse of a hasMany relationship, define a relationship function on the child model which calls the belongsTo method:

You need to create a belongsTo to relation on your user model.

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
    }
}
```